# Bootstrap Navbar pushing page too wide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I can't quite figure out why the navbar is doing this, but I think it started from when I added the collapsable functionality for mobile devices to it. Now, whichever size the screen is the navbar adds on an extra 10px or so to the screen width, creating an awkward gap on the right side of the screen. I thought this could be something to do with the containers, but removing this or changing position has no effect. I also tried:

```
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
```

But this made no difference. The navbar currently looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
      target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/aboutme">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="/cv">C.V.</a></li>
  <li><a href="/personalprojects">Personal projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

I really can't figure out why this is happening, so would be grateful for help, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

It was simply because I hadn't used bootstrap containers correctly. All fixed! :-)